# Change FOREIGN KEY action on large table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a large table (large enough to break my query) and I need to change `ON DELETE` from `RESTRICT` to `CASCASDE`, the problem is when I execute query [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548365/how-to-change-action-for-a-foreign-key):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP FOREIGN KEY my_key;
```

I'm getting error [`Mysql server has gone away`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html). I understand that I could set timeout for hours and hours of time, but is that the right way to go?

Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: hackish workaround: dump the table to file, then reload after making the key change?

Comment: @MarcB wouldn't that be slower than letting InnoDB taking care about it?

Comment: @Vyktor, this hack is very often faster, especially if you have your index on text columns.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In MySQL 8, there is a solution!

Using `ALGORITHM = INPLACE` will make adding/dropping a foreign key almost instant. Note that `foreign_key_checks = OFF;` must be set before adding the foreign key.

**Example:**

```
SET SESSION foreign_key_checks = OFF;

ALTER TABLE `my_schema`.`my_table`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `my_column`,
  ALGORITHM = INPLACE,
  LOCK = NONE;

ALTER TABLE `my_schema`.`my_table` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `my_constraint`
  FOREIGN KEY (`my_column`)
  REFERENCES `my_schema`.`my_other_table` (`my_other_column`)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
  ALGORITHM = INPLACE,
  LOCK = NONE;
  
SET SESSION foreign_key_checks = ON;
```

Note that this approach comes with a few [downsides](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312541/what-are-the-possible-downsides-or-consequences-of-using-algorithm-inplace-lock).

Hope this helps!